# Angular Universal: exclude node-only dependencies from bundling

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

I have an app built with angular universal `"@nguniversal/express-engine": "^9.1.1"`. I'm trying to add a server-side node canvas (`"canvas": "^2.6.1"`) to render certain images on the server. I don't need this library to be available on client side and thus want to exclude it from the bundle.

When trying to run the app with `npm run dev:ssr` though - I get errors that are related to that library:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are 
configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
this.debug is not a function
```

After some research I found that `externalDependencies` option was added to `angular.json` server build options. I tried to add the `canvas` library path to the array of `externalDependencies` but that doesn't give any result. Error is still there. And build is failing.

Currently I'm using the dynamic `import()` to load the canvas library into one of angular services if the platform is `server`. For some reason I assumed that it won't try to bundle dynamically imported scripts by default.
Maybe there's some other work-around.

So, to summarize, ideally, I would like to have a certain service that is only available on server-side and that would use the `canvas` library inside it. And won't break the angular build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Include in server bundle only**

> Currently I'm using the dynamic import() to load the canvas library into one of angular services if the platform is server

This includes this dependency into any bundle that uses your service (the chunk with canvas might still be lazy loaded - but webpack has to process it anyway).

An idiomatic way to do it in Angular is via dependency injection:

```
// no side effect here - safe to import in browser or server files
// canvas-polyfill.token.ts
export type PolyfillLoader = () => Promise<any>;
export const CANVAS_POLYFILL_LOADER = new InjectionToken<PolyfillLoader>();

// app.server.module.ts
const canvasLoader = () => import('canvas');

@NgModule({
   ...
   providers: [{provide: CANVAS_POLYFILL_LOADER, useValue: canvasLoader}]
})
export class AppServerModule {}

// your service
@Injectable()
class MyService {
  constructor(@Optional() @Inject(CANVAS_POLYFILL_LOADER) private polyfillLoader: PolyfillLoader) {}

  doYourStuff() {
    const whenReady = this.polyfillLoader ? this.polyfillLoader() : Promise.resolve();

    return whenReady.then(() => {
      // do something useful
    })
  }
}
```

**Webpack issue**

Having said all above - there is still no guarantee that angular's webpack will be able to process this dependency, when building a server bundle.
If you want to avoid including it into your bundle and keep external, you can set `bundleDependencies: false` option for your server builder in `angular.json`.
It has a side effect of not removing any debug code from angular libraries, though - so you would need to make extra steps to prepare your app for production (see https://angular.io/guide/ivy-compatibility#payload-size-debugging for some hints)